# In terminal vim, how do I prevent ghost echoing while running a shell command via system()

Tags: shell, vim

In terminal vim, even when running with `vim -u NONE`, all keys pressed during a call to `system()` are echoed back, once for each call to `system()`. To reproduce in vim do:

```
:call system("sleep 1")|call system ("sleep 1")|call system ("sleep 1")
```

And press `asdf` or whatever right away after hitting enter, you should see it get echo'd out 3 times. This isn't terrible, but what is is that the characters will often stick around and require a `:redraw!` to get rid of.

So the question is, how do I prevent that echoing? `:redraw!` is not a an answer I'm looking for. My particular use case is as part of an complete function and redrawing causes a flash that isn't ok with me.

Things that don't work:

1. `silent! call system("sleep 1")`
2. `system("stty -echo; sleep 1")`

Comment: you do not *necessarily* need to do `:redraw!`, but just Control-L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it by using vim's python integration to make system calls. Python does not echo keypresses while it is running commands.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I don't think there's much you can do about it. It's the way `vim` has been implemented that is a problem here and doing lazy redrawings of the UI is part of it. So it's not a bug, it's a feature ™©®

Comment: Yeah, the lazy redrawing is fine, I just want to suppress the buffered output in the first place. You may be right though, it may not be possible, vim may just set the terminal mode to echo when going into a system call, that'd make it behave just like bash does while running something long.